# How to add multiple parameters in get_permalinks function

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to give permalinks url for particular link 
I am using below code for permalinks 
`<a href="<?php echo get_permalink('280&id='.$dealID); ?>" >Test</a>`
But this is not working me, can anyone please tell me how can i pass multiple parameters in get permalink function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only parameters accepted [are $id and $leavename](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

Try using [add_query_arg()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/)
You could just do something like this:

```
<?php
// This would output 'http://blog.example.com/2009/04/16/?id=dealIdValue'
echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'id', $dealId, get_permalink(280) ) );
```

Comment: If i use it like `<?php echo get_permalink(280) ; ?>` then page shows with blank data, but if i use it like `<?php echo get_permalink(280) . '&id='. $dealID; ?>` then it show me page not found

Comment: Is that because the url ends with a / before the query string?